# How to use MariaDB devservices on Quarkus tests?

Tags: mariadb, quarkus

I'm trying to use Quarkus with a MariaDB image for testing.

When launching a test with `mvn integration-test`, I get the following:

```
Unable to start devservices for default datasource as this datasource type (mariadb) does not support devservices
```

My `application.properties` is the following:

```
quarkus_profile=test
%test.quarkus.datasource.devservices=true
%test.quarkus.datasource.devservices.image-name=mariadb_image
%test.quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mariadb
%test.quarkus.datasource.username=root
%test.quarkus.datasource.password=root
```

Quarkus version: `2.4.1.Final`

Comment: Interesting that [dev services](https://quarkus.io/guides/dev-services) lists using [test container](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/mariadb/) of which there is a MariaDB module.

Comment: After a bit of playing around I noticed that setting `quarkus.datasource.devservices.image-name=mariadb:10.6` and `quarkus.datasource.db-kind=` forces TestContainers to start a container for MariaDB but MySQL dev services are also started (likely from the db-kind change). It seems as soon as Quarkus decides the db-kind lacks dev services it ignores image-name that may be trying to help it match a valid image.

Comment: I've created [an issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/29891) on GitHub and it seems like a fix is now in the works.

Answer (score 0):

This post/question is almost 2 years old, but I don't like unanswered questions.

Using the last version of Quarkus, 3.7.2 MariaDB is definitely supported as one can see [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/databases-dev-services). You don't need to add any configurations at all, but of course you can.
**Dev Services** are enabled per default, so you don't need even:

```
%test.quarkus.datasource.devservices=true
```

Docker must be be of course installed on your machine.